# Как почистить проект на GitHub

Tags: git

У меня есть учебный проект на GitHub.
Еще когда начинал его делать, по незнанию напихал туда кучу ненужных фалов:
jar и idea и т.д.
Проект старый и там уже очень много коммитов.
А есть какой то простой способ почистить его от этого мусора?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно с помощью Git запустить данный скрипт ниже:

```
git rm -r --cached **/*.jar
```

Если запустить его из корневой папки проекта, то он потрёт все файлы с расширением `.jar` в проекте. Для `.idea` и остальных процедура такая же, только расширения поменять в скрипте.